# Find duplicate elements in vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector which holds the identifier of an element along with the x and Y coordinates. What I want to do is check to see if they have the same x and y coordinates? - and if they do delete one of them (based on another field).

I did find on Google about the  "unique" function, however, because all of the identifiers are unique this wouldn't work ? Correct?

I was thinking about going through each of the items in the vector comparing, using a nested for loop, is there a better way?

Thanks
J

Comment: isn't a `set` a better way of doing what you want to do, I mean use a `set` in the first place.

Comment: `std::unique` is the way to go. Look at the overloads of the function, you can specify yourself how to compare elements.

Comment: each of the fields in the vector is a class. I don't think that the set system would work.

Comment: @KingJohnno Each field is a class? Are you sure you don't mean an "object" or in other words "instance of a class"?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, sorry. It has been a long day!

Comment: Rough idea: declare a temporary `std::map<Point, std::vector<your_vector::iterator>>` (if you don't have a Point type, use std::pair<double,double> instead) and fill it with a loop like this: `my_map[your_vector[i].xy].push_back(your_vector[i]);`. Afterwards, iterate the map and if the vector has more than 1 element, decide which one to delete.

Comment: I think best way is to create compare operator for your objects. Than sort the vector. And than you use unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just went ahead and wrote some example thing. I hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;


// Sample coordinate class 
class P {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    P() : x(0), y(0) {}
    P(int i, int j) : x(i), y(j) {}
};


// Just for printing out
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const P& p) {
    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
    return o;
}

// Tells us if one P is less than the other
bool less_comp(const P& p1, const P& p2) {

    if(p1.x > p2.x)
        return false;
    if(p1.x < p2.x)
        return true;

    // x's are equal if we reach here.
    if(p1.y > p2.y)
        return false;
    if(p1.y < p2.y)
        return true;

    // both coordinates equal if we reach here.
    return false;
}


// Self explanatory
bool equal_comp(const P& p1, const P& p2) {

    if(p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y) 
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{

  vector<P> v;
  v.push_back(P(1,2));
  v.push_back(P(1,3));
  v.push_back(P(1,2));
  v.push_back(P(1,4));

  // Sort the vector. Need for std::unique to work.
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less_comp);

  // Collect all the unique values to the front.
  std::vector<P>::iterator it;
  it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), equal_comp);
  // Resize the vector. Some elements might have been pushed to the end.
  v.resize( std::distance(v.begin(),it) );

  // Print out.
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<P>(cout, "\n"));

}
```

---

> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 1 4

Answer (score 4):

You could use [std::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique) to discard duplicates. This, however, doesn't allow you to do anything with the removed elements. They are just dropped from the container. When you need to do this, you can use this approach:

Use [vector.sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) with a custom compare function which compares the x- and y-coordinates. Then iterate the vector once, comparing each element to the previous one.

When you don't want to change the order of the vector, you could also iterate the vector from start to finish, and compare each element to all elements with a higher index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    Position current = vector.at(i);
    for (int j = i+1; j < vector.size(); j++) {
         if current.isEqualPosition(vector.at(j)) {
             // found a duplicate
         }
    }
}
```

By the way: Depending on your exact requirements, a better way to handle objects in 2d-space could be a custom data structure like a [two-dimensional tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Hm this has complexity O(N^2)

Comment: @hr_117 And so does the solution by Named. Do you think std::sort and std::unique are magic?

Comment: No I'm not really think this would be magic. ;-) But sort should be O(N * logN) and unique hopefully only O(N).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a combination of [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (or [`std::ranges::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) in C++20) and [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).